# Webview Resizing without wrapping Text and to Scale any HTML page to fit Window or Parent Layout

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-webview, android-view

I tried resizing Webview to fit Window, but webview ever resizes itself to wrap the content .
It is important , text should not wrap as it zooms, or when it fits window.

I have explained all these details in attached picture, and requirement.

When setUseWideViewPort(true) is used,blank space is resulted in portrait mode and whereas in landscape mode, content height and webview height is still bigger than parent layout.

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank you

As I don't have enough reputation, I am sharing image in google drive,

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FPNi6tY-UKdEVFbXpVeVEyQms/edit)